# Reading list of queries from a file and executing them in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a list of queries stored in a text file(csv or any delimeter separated) queries and want to execute them one by one in pyspark. I am very new to spark and wanted to know if there is any related spark api which I can use for doing this.

```
sample data 
C1 | C2 | C3
1  | 2  | 3
0  | 0  | 0
```

sample queries text file
select * from sample_data_table where C1 = 0,
select * from sample_data_table where C1 != 0

output

```
df1 ==> C1 | C2 | C3
        0  | 0  | 0

df2 ==> C1 | C2 | C3
        1  | 2  | 3
```

Comment: Is it a text/csv file with singe column and each row with single query or is it like quer1,query2,query3,..so on ?

Comment: it can be any of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by reading file as a dataframe and passing each query to spark.sql() method.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.text("file.txt")
# To have single query per row
rows = df.select(explode(split('value', ','))).collect()

'''
Using collect is not recommended since it brings all the data to driver.
If the driver memory is not enough we get OOM errors.
We can do something like
df.foreach(#...)
But in your case we need to use spark session object within foreach.
Code with in foreach will be sent to executors and will not be able to access 
spark session within executor and you will get errors.
That's why I used collect(). Need to check some alternatives here.
'''
for sql in rows:
    spark.sql(sql[0]).show()
```